# converting data structure in JS

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I got this problem, I don't know why I'm struggling to resolve it.
So I'm using ES6 with react
and I appreciate all the help to turn this

> `[ { a : [{} , ....] , b : {}  } , {...}, ... ]`

to this

> `[ { a : [{} ,  ....] , b : [{}] }, {...}, ...  ]`

Comment: `v[0].b = [v[0].b]`

Comment: hi, thank you for your time,  please can you explain to me, I'm a noob in changing data structures, so what happened to a : []

Comment: the only diff i can see between your two lines is array item 0, object property `b`'s values are inside an array, my previous comment is doing that, its replacing item 0, object property `b`'s value with `b`'s value wrapped in an array, simplz.. the issue comes when the value is not there but thats beyond the scope of the question, you should use a loop instead with a check on it, or fix the source which produces it vs changing it after

Comment: I'm not getting it xD , so the array item 0 is an object that contains two properties, the first one is an  array of object and the second is an object, so I'm trying to change the second property into an array of objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need rewrite with a array assigned

Acess index in array and current "b" object look this example bellow

```js
let problem = [ { a : [{} , {}], b : {} }, {}]
problem[0].b = [ problem[0].b ]

console.log(problem)
```